# Словарь слов с разными ударениями

Tags: фонетика

В каком словаре можно найти, есть ли различия в словах с разными ударениями: например, гОловы и головЫ?

У меня задание по русскому языку:

> Пользуясь словарем, определите, есть ли различия в словах с разными ударениями, укажите эти различия.

И дается пример: гОловы - головЫ - ударение различает разные формы слова: гОловф - множественное число, именительный падеж; головЫ - единственное число, родительный падеж. изомЕтрия - изометрИя - различий нет, допускаются оба варианта.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня задание по русскому языку "Пользуясь словарем, определите, есть ли различия в словах с разными ударениями, укажите эти различия." И дается пример: гОловы - головЫ -ударение различает разные формы слова: гОловф - множественное число, именительный падеж; головЫ - ед.число, родит.падеж.  изомЕтрия - изометрИя - различий нет, допускаются оба варианта.

Answer (score 2):

Существует ["Грамматический словарь русского языка"](http://www.udarenieru.ru/index.php) доступный в сети, где показываются ударения для единственного и множественного чисел в зависимости от падежа и другая информация, введите ваше слово `голова` в его поисковике и вы получите исчерпывающую информацию, см. по ссылке  [здесь](http://www.udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on)

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном Вами примере никакого различия в словах нет, так как это разные формы одного и того же слова "голова" (множественное число и родительный падеж). Найти эту информацию Вы можете в любом толковом и даже орфографическом словарях. А есть слова,где от ударения зависит смысл слова, например "посажЁный" (отец) и "посАженный" (цветок). Правда, эти слова еще и пишутся по-разному.

Comment: Виктор1799 это уже ни в какие ворота не лезет.
Беретесь делайть домашнее задания - делайте его хотя бы правильно.

Comment: Моего ума не хватает, чтобы понять, в чем же я не прав, написав, что "гОловы" и "головЫ" -это одно и то же слово, но разные его формы. И что нового написали Вы по сравнению с той информацией, которую представил я?

Comment: Вы не понимаете разницы между "есть разница" и "нет разницы"?

Читайте:
В задании:
>ударение различает разные формы слова

В вашем ответе:
>В приведенном Вами примере никакого различия в словах нет

Двойка будет на Вашей совести.

А про омографы с разным ударением в задании вообще речи не идёт.
Кстати пара посаженный-посаженый строго говоя омографичной тоже не является. Ё и Е разные буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Ярослава, ваше задание сформулировано так, что вам надо найти различия именно в формах слова. Разумеется, различия между "гОловы" и "головЫ" есть.

Словарь можно использовать любой, где даются разные формы. Слова, в которых нет различий (кроме самого места ударения) там будут приведены в заголовках статей. 
Формы же слов, где есть различия вы можете восстановить, задавая например вопрос. "ГОловы - что?", "ГоловЫ -  (нет) чего?". Обратите еще внимание на число. ГОловы - много (две и более), головЫ - одна (т.е. "одной головы").